# jRebel not work with Message resource bundle

Tags: spring, resourcebundle, jrebel

I am using jRebel version 5.0.0 in my Spring project. Everything works well, any changes in Java, JSP or JS files was affected immediately. But when I modify some message keys in MessageResource.properties file, it does not reload the new modification. All of my resource bundle files are in same directory: **myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF**;

and in target folder (built files) **myproject\target\myproject\WEB-INF**.
I do not use external jRebel config file, but jRebel plugin for Eclipse, so I found the auto-generated jRebel config file in myproject\target\myproject\WEB-INF\classes\jrebel.xml.
Here is its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">

    <classpath>
        <dir name="D:/workspace/.projects/myproject/target/myproject/WEB-INF/classes">
        </dir>
    </classpath>

    <web>
        <link target="/">
            <dir name="D:/workspace/.projects/myproject/src/main/webapp">
            </dir>
        </link>
    </web>

</application>
```

Could you please help me this issue? Thank you so much.

Comment: How is the properties file used? Perhaps the values are just cached and the cache is never reinitialized.

Comment: BTW, it should be rebel.xml, not jrebel.xml